# Angular 2 & BreezeJS & SystemJS Build - Multiple anonymous defines

Tags: angular, breeze, systemjs-builder

I'm trying to build my Angular 2 & BreezeJS application by using SystemJS Build tool through gulpfile.
However when I try to execute the build task, I get `Multiple anonymous defines` error.

On the other hand, if I run the application by directly including `system.js` and `systemjs.config.js` to my page, it works without any problem.

So, what does this error exactly mean, and is it possible to build my application with systemjs-builder?

- breeze-client: 1.6.0
- systemjs: 0.19.41
- systemjs-builder: 0.15.34

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        paths: {
            "npm:": "node_modules/"
        },
        map: {
            "app": "app/main",
            "@angular/core": "npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd",
            "@angular/common": "npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd",
            "@angular/compiler": "npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd",
            "@angular/http": "npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd",
            "rxjs": "npm:rxjs",
            "datajs": "npm:datajs/index",
            "breeze-client": "npm:breeze-client/breeze.debug",
            "breeze-bridge-angular2": "npm:breeze-bridge-angular2/index",
        }
    });
})(this);
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task("build", function () {
    var Builder = require("systemjs-builder");
    var builder = new Builder("", "./systemjs.config.js");

    return builder.buildStatic("app", "./app/app.js", { encodeNames: false })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("error", error);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `breeze.debug.js` contains the core breeze files *and all the adapters* in it.

The solution is to use `breeze.base.debug.js` with separate adapters.

One important difference is that you need to explicitly import additional adapters to your application, and I believe the ideal location to do that is your `entity manager`.

Here is a working example. It also contains `build-breeze.debug` task that is using `breeze.debug.js` and failing with `Multiple anonymous defines` error.
https://github.com/forCrowd/Labs-BreezeJS-SystemJSBuilder